# How can I fill a screen with a layout using xaml - xamarin.forms?

Tags: xaml, mobile, xamarin.forms

I have a Grid and I want that it fill the screen.
Can I use horizontal options, for example?

```
  <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Image="imgteste.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Button>
        <Label Text="User name:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></Label>
        <Label Text="User name:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
        <Label Text="User name:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></Label>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` like you thought.

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill"
      VerticalOptions="Fill">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Image="imgteste.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Button>
    <Label Text="User name:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></Label>
    <Label Text="User name:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
    <Label Text="User name:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></Label>
</Grid>
```